# Accidental JavaScript redirct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I have a form that adds an item to a list when I press enter or hit a submit button.  I'm not sure what I've changed, but suddenly pressing enter seems to redirect the URL, while clicking the button acts normally.

The HTML portion looks like this:

```
<form id="add-ingr">
    <input class="new-ingredient" type="text" size="50" name="new-ingredient" placeholder=" Your ingredient"></input>
    <img id="check" src="imgs/check.png" alt=""/>
</form>
```

The jQuery is:

```
$('#check').click(function () {
    addIngredient('new-ingredient');
});
$('.new-ingredient').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        addIngredient('new-ingredient');
    }
});
```

So it's running the same function either way.  In both cases, it successfully adds the ingredient to the list, but in the 2nd case, the page is redirected from "recipe.html" to "recipe.html?new-ingredient=".
And here's the part that really confuses me: when I add an extra input to the form, this problem doesn't occur when I press enter in either box:

```
<form id="add-ingr">
    <input class="new-ingredient" type="text" size="50" name="new-ingredient" placeholder=" Your ingredient"></input>
    <img id="check" src="imgs/check.png" alt=""/>
    <input type="text"></input>
</form>
```

Also, if I add in an actual button (not my clickable image), it redirects like pressing enter, even though I have no code to do anything if the button is pressed.  In this case, the extra input field has no effect.

```
<form id="add-ingr">
    <input class="new-ingredient" type="text" size="50" name="new-ingredient" placeholder=" Your ingredient"></input>
    <img id="check" src="imgs/check.png" alt=""/>
    <button id="button">Add Ingredient</button>
</form>
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.  Even if I get rid of the jQuery to perform an action when I hit enter, this still happens.  I'm new to JavaScript, so sorry if this is something obvious, but I'd really appreciate some help.

I can also provide more of my code if it's relevant, but I didn't want to clog things up with a ton of code.

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault()` on submitting the form or `return false` at the end.

Comment: Remove the form tags, you don't appear to need them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting enter (or clicking the button if its there) is submitting the form (this makes it appear to "redirect the URL"). You need to prevent that from happening with `e.preventDefault()`. So in the click listener:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  addIngredient('new-ingredient');
});
```

Put that in each of the listeners, or get rid of your form tags so there isn't anything to submit (as was mentioned in the comments).

Comment: This works.  I ended up just getting rid of the form tags and it did the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely blame you for being confused. The browser default behavior is to perform the "submit" action, whatever it is, when someone presses enter while a field in the form is highlighted. As elclanrs said, you can override the submit action; in fact, I'm pretty sure in JQuery it's just this:

```
$('#add-ingr').submit(function(e) {
  if ('event is not coming from button')...{
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

I'm afraid I couldn't explain why adding a blank input changed the effect, though. Through my laziness, I have also left you the work of determining the best way of allowing actual submissions, though (if the form gets submitted to the server, you won't want to block submit every time)